# NAudio - Buffer Full after

Tags: c#, .net, audio, signal-processing, naudio

I'm trying to create an audio loopback using [NAudio](https://naudio.codeplex.com/) in C# and I keep getting this message:

> NAudio.MmException was unhandled
>
> AlreadyAllocated calling waveInOpen

Here is my code:

```
if (lstDevices.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;

int deviceNumber = lstDevices.SelectedItems[0].Index;

sourceStream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveIn();
sourceStream.DeviceNumber = deviceNumber;
sourceStream.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(44100, NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(deviceNumber).Channels);

NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider waveIn = new NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider(sourceStream);

waveOut = new NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut();
waveOut.Init(waveIn);

sourceStream.StartRecording();
waveOut.Play();
```

I'm stumped. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What line is the exception thrown from?

Comment: the error message suggests you are attempting to start recording on a device on which you are already recording.

Comment: @MarkHeath Heath, I tried to Stop and Dispose any stream that was active but with no luck.

Comment: @jaket It is thrown from "Application.Run(new Form1());" in Program.cs.

Comment: @Dave, that's the bottom of the call stack, but is of very little use. In the visual studio menu: click Debug/Exceptions and then check Break when Thrown for all of the Common Language Runtime exceptions.

Comment: @Dave - it could be that another application entirely has got exclusive access to that soundcard